# Hana SQL , Is there a way to use mapping/setup table of constants?

Tags: sql, hana

Is there a way use mapping table instead of hardcoding of values and their replacements?

mapping table

| value | replacement |
| --- | --- |
| N | Module Not turned In |
| PC | Pending Corrections |

```
LT_REVIEW_STATUS = SELECT DISTINCT A.PRUEFLOS,
CASE WHEN UPPER(A.KTEXTLOS) LIKE '%:N%' THEN 'Module Not turned In'
WHEN UPPER(A.KTEXTLOS) LIKE '%PC%' THEN 'Pending Corrections'
WHEN UPPER(A.KTEXTLOS) LIKE '%RC%' THEN 'Not yet reviewed'
WHEN UPPER(A.KTEXTLOS) LIKE '%:O%' THEN 'Close Out'
WHEN UPPER(A.KTEXTLOS) LIKE '%RV%' THEN 'Reviewed' 
ELSE 'N/A' END AS REVIEW_STATUS
FROM :LT_FIRST_QALS A;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This requirement can be fullfilled with a join to a reference table.

Given a reference table `CODE_LOOKUP` that looks like this:

| MATCH_CODE | STATUS_TEXT |
| --- | --- |
| :N | Module Not turned In |
| PC | Pending Corrections |
| RC | Not yet reviewed |
| :0 | Close Out |
| RV | Reviewed |

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
     A.PRUEFLOS
   , IFNULL(CL.STATUS_TEXT, 'N/A') AS REVIEW_STATUS
FROM 
     :LT_FIRST_QALS A
     LEFT OUTER JOIN CODE_LOOKUP CL
     ON LOCATE (UPPER(A.KTEXTLOS), CL.MATCHCODE) > 0
```

see the documentation for `LOCATE` https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/20e3b6b77519101485e6bd62f7018f75.html